# Laravel 5.4 FormRequest forbiddenResponse() method has been replaced by failedAuthorization()

Tags: redirect, request, laravel-5.4

As precised in the title, I noticed that the `forbiddenResponse()` method has been removed from the FormRequest in Laravel 5.4.

This method has been replaced by the `failedAuthorization()` method that now triggers an `AuthorizationException`.

This causes me troubles because I would need to make redirections from the form request and it seems that it is not possible anymore.

Would anybody have a solution in this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `App\Exceptions\Handler` and add this inside the `render` method:

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
    // Do what you want here, Response, Redirect...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Syl, this si quite ingenious ;) I try this tomorrow !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I became a father since my last message ;)

Here is what I have done since you gave me your tip.

I created a BaseRequest class that my formRequests extends. In it, I have override the `failedAuthorization` method like that :

```
protected function failedAuthorization()  
{
    $exception = new AuthorizationException('This action is unauthorized.');
    $exception->error_message = $this->error_message;
    $exception->redirect = $this->getRedirectUrl();
    $exception->dontFlash = $this->dontFlash;           
    throw $exception;
}
```

In the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, I have added the following treatment in the `render` method :

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {  
    // ajax or api call  
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        // treatment
    }

    // we notify the current user with a modal
    if($exception->error_message) Modal::alert($exception->error_message, 'error');

    if ($exception->redirect){
        return redirect()->to($exception->redirect)->withInput(request()->except($exception->dontFlash));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput(request()->except($exception->dontFlash));
    }
}
```

With this process, I have a satisfying treatment with a customizable formRequest use. But I still find that it is a bit messy and not really clean. If you or someone else has a better way to implement this, I would be glad to discuss it with you.

Comment: This will be more cleaner very soon, check out: https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/weekend-laravel-improvements-26d0d230e48f